# How do I import a double parentheses function in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, require

I am trying to import this: `require('nforce-metadata')(nforce)` in typescript. What is the way to do it? So far I tried `import '('nforce-metadata')(nforce)'` but didn't work. Any help? Also, I don't want it to assign it to any variable.
Basically what I was doing is `require('nforce-metadata')(nforce)` directly and not assigning to variable.

Answer (score 3):

You have to import it first, then initialize it.

**Example:**

```js
import nforce from 'nforce'
import nforceMetadata from 'nforce-metadata'

// Initialize it
nforceMetadata(nforce)
```

Comment: didn't need it to assign to readyNforce wanted side-effects(run function on load). Thanks!